# Unoconv fill merged cells with value

Tags: awk, unoconv

I am using unoconv to convert different xlsx reports into csv. One of the reports has a merged cell like below.

```
Column_1   Column_2  Column_3  Column_4
C          ABC       DEF       123
           ABC       DEF       123
           ABC       DEF       123
```

Whenever I convert the xlsx file into csv. The merged cell which is column_1 is not filled with values like this.

```
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4
C,ABC,DEF,123
,ABC,DEF,123
,ABC,DEF,123
```

Is there any option in unoconv to fill the merged cells with value? Or is there any possible work around with this using awk maybe?

Desired Ouput:

```
Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4
C,ABC,DEF,123
C,ABC,DEF,123
C,ABC,DEF,123
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{$1=$1;print;next} !/^ +/{val=$1;$1=$1} /^ +/{$1=val OFS $1} 1' OFS=","   Input_file
```

Comment: @user2058738. it worked well and fine for me, could you please check if you have control M characters in your Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` let me know then.

Comment: I've checked and my input file does not have control M

Comment: @user2058738, any error you are getting? or which OS are you using? please do let me know.

Comment: no any errors actually. its just that the blank cell is still not populated. OS is CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

Comment: @user2058738, when you are running is it not giving anything on terminal? or you are expecting output should be saved into Input_file itself, please clarify once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168533/discussion-between-user2058738-and-ravindersingh13).